# Incrementing/decrementing score value in rock/paper/scissors React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, frontend

I am new to React and to this platform, and I am building a rock/scissors/paper app with React.js.
The app works well, but I cannot increment the score value of the game. If the player wins I would like to increment it of +1, if the CPU wins decrement it by -1. (draw nothing happens)
I can see the score in the screen, because I set the state of  to the value, I just cannot update it.

I think the problem is mainly on my setScore() function. I think is correct that I pass it from  as a prop to , but in  I don't know exactly how to call the method and then eventually pass it back to .

I know is a lot of code but essentially I just would like to pass a setScore() method down to a child component, call it, and the pass the result back to the parent component.

Do you have any idea how I could fix this problem ?

[You can also check Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-ardinghelli-96sum?file=/src/images/icon-scissors.svg)

Thank you very much in advance!!

App.js

```
import React from "react"
import Header from "./components/Header"
import Main from "./components/Main"
import Footer from "./components/Footer"

import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
      score: 12
    }
    this.setScore = this.setScore.bind(this)
  }

  /*here i create the setScore method*/
  setScore() {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return {
        score: prevState.score + 1
      }
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="container">
          <Header 
              rock = "ROCK" 
              paper = "PAPER" 
              scissors = "SCISSORS" 
              score = {this.state.score} 
          />
          /*here I pass the setScore method as a prop to my Main component (should I also pass the score 
           value as a parameter?)*/
          <Main setScore = {this.setScore}/>
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Main.js

```
import React from "react"
import Choice from "./Choice"
import TryAgain from "./TryAgain"

import paper from '../images/icon-paper.svg'
import rock from '../images/icon-rock.svg'
import scissors from '../images/icon-scissors.svg'

import './Main.css';

class Main extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            onScreen: true,
            choiceName: '',
            choiceImage: '',
            choiceBorderColor: '',
            choiceExtraBorderColor: '',
            houseChoice: '',
            results:'',
            score: 0,
            setScore: props.setScore
        }
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
        this.handleTryAgainClick = this.handleTryAgainClick.bind(this)
    }

    /*function that handles the user choice*/
    handleClick = (choiceName, choiceImage, choiceBorderColor, choiceExtraBorderColor) => () => {
        this.setState({
            onScreen: false,
            choiceName,
            choiceImage,
            choiceBorderColor,
            choiceExtraBorderColor,
        })

        /*function that get a random number between 0 and 2, and set this number to the house index*/
        function getRandomInt(max) {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
        }

        const index = getRandomInt(3)

        this.setState({
            houseChoice: index
        })

        const results = this.getResults(choiceName, index).toUpperCase()
        this.setState({
            results: results,
        })

        if(results === "WIN") {
            /*************what to put here*****************/
            const res = this.props.setScore
            console.log(res) /*here it prints the function itself!*/
            return {
                res
            }
        } else if (results === "LOSE" && this.state.score > 0) {
            /*************what to put here*****************/
            console.log(this.state.score)
            this.setState((prevState) => {
                return {
                    score: prevState.score - 1
                }
            })
        }
        else {
            console.log(this.state.score)
            this.setState((prevState) => {
                return {
                    score: prevState.score
                }
            })
        }
    }

    /*function that get the main logic and the results of the game*/
    getResults(choiceName, houseChoice) {
        if(choiceName === "paper" && houseChoice === 0) {
            return "draw"
        } else if(choiceName === "paper" && houseChoice === 1) {
            return "lose"
        } else if(choiceName === "paper" && houseChoice === 2) {
            return "win"
        }
        if(choiceName === "rock" && houseChoice === 0) {
            return "lose"
        } else if(choiceName === "rock" && houseChoice === 1) {
            return "win"
        } else if(choiceName === "rock" && houseChoice === 2) {
            return "draw"
        }
        if(choiceName === "scissors" && houseChoice === 0) {
            return "win"
        } else if(choiceName === "scissors" && houseChoice === 1) {
            return "draw"
        } else if(choiceName === "scissors" && houseChoice === 2) {
            return "lose"
        }
    }

    /*function that switches the screen and resets the index of the house*/
    handleTryAgainClick() {
        this.setState({
            onScreen: true,
            houseChoice: ''
        })
    }
    
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                {/*HOME PAGE*/}
                <div className="main-container" style={{display: (this.state.onScreen ? "block" : "none")}}>
                    <div className="triangle-container">
                        <div onClick={this.handleClick}>
                            <Choice
                                name="paper"
                                image={paper} 
                                borderColor="hsl(230, 89%, 62%)" 
                                extraBorderColor="hsl(230, 89%, 65%)"
                                handleClick={this.handleClick}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div onClick={this.handleClick}>
                            <Choice
                                name="scissors"
                                image={scissors} 
                                borderColor="hsl(39, 89%, 49%)" 
                                extraBorderColor="hsl(40, 84%, 53%)"
                                handleClick={this.handleClick}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div style={{gridArea: "bottom"}} onClick={this.handleClick}>
                            <Choice 
                                name="rock"
                                image={rock} 
                                borderColor="hsl(349, 71%, 52%)" 
                                extraBorderColor="hsl(349, 70%, 56%)"
                                handleClick={this.handleClick}
                            />
                        </div>    
                    </div>
                </div>

                {/*RESULT PAGE*/}
                <div className="result-wrapper" style={{display: (!this.state.onScreen ? "grid" : "none")}}>

                    <div className="user-result-box">
                        <h4 className="result-title">YOU PICKED</h4>
                        <div 
                            className="elem-container result-container"
                            style={{
                                borderColor: this.state.choiceBorderColor, 
                                color: this.state.choiceExtraBorderColor
                            }}
                        >
                            <img src={this.state.choiceImage} className="choice-image" alt="img" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="house-result-box">
                        <h4 className="result-title">THE HOUSE PICKED</h4>

                        {this.state.houseChoice === 0 ? (

                            /*1*/
                            <div 
                                className="elem-container result-container"
                                style={{ 
                                    borderColor:"hsl(230, 89%, 62%)",
                                    color:"hsl(230, 89%, 65%)" 
                                }}
                            >
                                <img src={paper} className="choice-image" alt="img" />
                            </div>

                        ) : ( 

                            this.state.houseChoice === 1 ? (
                            
                            /*2*/
                            <div 
                                className="elem-container result-container"
                                style={{ 
                                    borderColor:"hsl(39, 89%, 49%)", 
                                    color:"hsl(40, 84%, 53%)" 
                                }}
                            >
                                <img src={scissors} className="choice-image" alt="img" />
                            </div>

                        ) : (

                            /*3*/
                            <div 
                                className="elem-container result-container"
                                    style={{ 
                                        borderColor:"hsl(349, 71%, 52%)", 
                                        color:"hsl(349, 70%, 56%)" 
                                    }}
                            >
                                <img src={rock} className="choice-image" alt="img" />
                            </div>
                        ))
                        }

                    </div>
                    <div className="final-result-container">
                    <h1 className="bold">YOU {this.state.results}</h1>
                        <TryAgain onClick={this.handleTryAgainClick}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        )
    }
}

export default Main


  [1]: https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-ardinghelli-96sum?file=/src/images/icon-scissors.svg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**App.js**

```js
setScore(value) {
  if (this.state.score > 0) {
    this.setState({
      score: this.state.score + value
    })
  }
}
```

**Main.js**

```js
if (results === 'WIN') {
  /*************what to put here*****************/
  this.props.setScore(1)
} else if (results === 'LOSE') {
  /*************what to put here*****************/
  this.props.setScore(-1)
}
```

**Score.js**

```js
import React from "react";
import "./Score.css";

class Score extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="score-text">SCORE</div>
        <div className="score-value">{this.props.score}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Score;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I did as you suggested but the value still doesn't change. I also tried to change my previous <Main setScore = {this.setScore}/> call into <Main setScore = {() => this.setScore(val)}/> because now setScore has a paramenter, but I get that 'val' is not defined.

Comment: Where did you updated it ? I don't see it. Like I told you I tried to use <Main setScore = {() => this.setScore(val)}/> but I keep on getting that val is not defined. Instead if I try  <Main setScore = {() => this.setScore()}/> the score value is still not changing.

Comment: updated my answer. You can check it and try. Also stay with `<Main setScore = {this.setScore}/>`

Comment: So now I can print out on the console the values of value and this.state.score. In particular, the value is correct (+1 if win, -1 if lose, 0 if draw) but this.state.score gets updated one iteration after the current one and it still does not update the UI (only on console)

Comment: is there still any problem? I think you can see changing score.

Comment: Yes :( now I can print out on the console the values of value and this.state.score. In particular, the value is correct (+1 if win, -1 if lose, 0 if draw) but this.state.score gets updated one iteration after the current one and it still does not update the UI (only on console)

Comment: I've updated my answer again. Also, plesae remove `score` and `setScore` in `Main.js` -> `constrcutor` -> `this.state = { ... }`

Comment: Nothing. Still the same and for some reason this.state.score gets updated only 1 game after the current one, and still nothing changing on the screen. Do you want that i link you my github account ? Btw, I am really appreciating your help. Thanks a lot

Comment: maybe you can upload your code to codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s

Comment: Yes sure i have updated my post with the codesandbox link. Thank you

Comment: Finally found the issue on Score.js. Please check my updated answer. You should use `props.score` directly. You've set `state.score` with `props.score` on `constructor`, which is just setting initial value. In this case, when the `props.score` is changed `state.score` doesn't been changed. That's why you couldn't see the score is being changed.

Comment: Thank you very much for everything!!! I appreciate your help a lot :) And yes you are right now it works as it should. Thanks